# Add some string after certain string

Tags: javascript

For example ,

Consider i have the below code in a `div`

```
var qty = document.getElementsByName('subForm_prodQtyForm')[0].value; 
var rate = document.getElementsByName('subForm_rateForm')[0].value;
```

I need Javascript code to replace the above code as below code . How to replace ??

```
var qty = document.getElementsByName('subForm_prodQtyForm_1')[0].value;
var rate = document.getElementsByName('subForm_rateForm_1')[0].value;
```

Comment: @mplungjan If you look in the revision history you'll see that invalid code was posted and it was fixed by another poster. OP's "question" doesn't make much sense. If he needs to replace the above as something else, then that's a conclusion - not a question. Before it was hard to see *what* had changed (specially as it was in one line)

Comment: append _1  in that string

Comment: @karthi That isn't a question. What is your *question*? Are you asking if you have to append `_1` to the string?

Comment: He has some code in a string - he needs to add _1 to it at a specific place - what is there not to understand?

Comment: @mplungjan The fact that he's adding the characters inside the name of the element? Does he want `subForm_rateForm` there as well? From a logical standpoint the attempted code makes no sense at all. If he just wants to append `_1` to `document.getElementsByName('subForm_prodQtyForm')[0].value`, then that should be the question.

Comment: @mplungjan you are correct. any idea to solve this ??

Comment: Why not use a text editor like vi, emacs, eclipse, etc. ? Are there many files to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your "code" are just strings in a div and they do not change, you can do

```
var div = document.getElementById("divId");
var text = div.innerHTML;
div.innerHTML=text.replace(/Form'/g,"Form_1'");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append _1, then you can use

```
str='subForm_prodQtyForm'+'_1';
var qty = document.getElementsByName(str)[0].value;
```

Or, If you need to replace that string with some other, You can use the following:

```
str="subForm_prodQtyForm";
strlbl = str.replace('subForm_prodQtyForm','subForm_prodQtyForm_1'); 
var qty = document.getElementsByName(strlbl)[0].value;
```

Comment: But if this is actually OPs question, why not simply replace the string in the code? Why use `document.getElementById('foo' + (true ? 'bar' : 'rab') + (10 + 113))` instead of `document.getElementById('foobar123')` when the result will *always* be the same? The simplest answer in this case would be "*move your cursor to right where you want to add the text, click and press the `_` button on your keyboard followed by `1`*".

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yes. we can replace it directly. But If the user wants to use the replaced string in particular places only, it can be used like this..(using replace in client-side scripting).. But the suggestion you have given is simplest i think in this case.